# Proving Monotonic Decrease of Kullback-Leibler Divergence in Iterative Method for Stationary Distribution Estimation

Tags: stationarity, markov-process, kullback-leibler

### Introduction

Consider a well-behaved Markov chain with desirable properties (irreducible, aperiodic, positive recurrent), characterized by a transition matrix $P$ and a stationary distribution $\pi$. The stationary distribution satisfies the equation:

$$
\pi = \pi P \tag 1
$$

Here, $\pi$ is a row vector whose summation equals 1.

In practice, solving $(1)$ directly for $\pi$ is feasible for small-dimensional matrices, but for larger matrices, an iterative approach is employed.

terative Method for Stationary Distribution Estimation:

Input: Transition matrix $P$, iteration error $\epsilon$

1. Initialize $\pi^{(0)}$ such that the elements sum to 1.
2. Compute $\pi^{(k)} = \pi^{(k-1)} P$.
3. If the error between $\pi^{(k)}$ and $\pi^{(k-1)}$ is less than $\epsilon$, stop iteration and output $\pi^{(k)}$. Otherwise, continue iterating.

**I hope to show Kullback-Leibler divergence $KL(\pi^{(k)} \mid \pi)$ is monotonically decreasing throughout the iteration process.**

### Numerical Simulation

To illustrate this monotonic decrease, a fifth-order transition matrix $P$ is considered.

$$
P = \begin{pmatrix}
0   & 0.25 & 0.25 & 0.25 & 0.25\\
0.2 & 0.2  & 0.2  & 0.2  & 0.2\\
0   & 0.5  & 0    & 0    & 0.5\\
0   & 1/3  & 1/3  & 0    & 1/3\\
0   & 1    & 0    & 0    & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The corresponding stationary distribution is $\pi = [0.08759124, 0.4379562, 0.1459854,  0.10948905, 0.2189781]$

Using a random initial distribution $\pi^{(0)} = [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2]$, the calculated KL divergences are as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
KL(\pi^{(0)} \mid \pi) = 0.1736967812\\ 
KL(\pi^{(1)} \mid \pi) = 0.0219343265\\
KL(\pi^{(2)} \mid \pi) = 0.0022525586\\
KL(\pi^{(3)} \mid \pi) = 0.0006414772\\
KL(\pi^{(4)} \mid \pi) = 0.0000681666\\
\end{align}
$$

This numerical simulation supports the observed monotonic decrease. The next step is to provide a rigorous proof of this phenomenon.

Note that the KL divergence is defined as:

$$
KL(\pi^{(k)} \mid \pi) = \sum_{i=1}^n \pi^{(k)}_i \log \frac{\pi^{(k)}_i}{\pi_i}
$$

```py
import numpy as np

# transition matrix
P = np.array([[0, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25],
              [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2],
              [0, 0.5, 0., 0., 0.5],
              [0, 1./3, 1./3, 0., 1./3],
              [0, 1., 0., 0., 0.]])
I = np.eye(P.shape[0])
A = I - P.T
b = np.ones_like(P[:, 0])
pi = np.linalg.solve(A, b)
pi = pi / np.sum(pi)  
print("True stationary distribution pi: ", pi)

# initial distribution
pi0 = np.array([0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2])

# compute KL divergence
eps = 1e-8
print(f"KL(pi{0:<2} || pi) = {np.sum(pi0 * np.log((pi0 + eps) / (pi + eps))):.10f}")
for i in range(10):
    pi0 = pi0.dot(P)
    kli = np.sum(pi0 * np.log((pi0 + eps) / (pi + eps)))
    print(f"KL(pi{i+1:<2} || pi) = {kli:.10f}")
```

Can anyone help to prove the statement or give a counterexample? Actually K-L divergence is not necessary we can only use L2 norm i.e. show that $|| \pi^{(k)} - \pi ||_2^2$ decreases to 0.

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: In other words, what I want to show is that $KL(xP \mid \pi) \le KL(x \mid \pi)$ for all $x$ with summation 1.